# How do I make my game music keep playing between scenes?

Tags: game-engine, scene

I'm making a game where each level has its own scene. When a level is completed it switches to the next scene and restarts the music that's playing. How do I make it so that the music plays continuously between scenes?

Answer (score 1):

- Add a `manager` scene, where stuff should happen independently from other scenes. You can set and remove scenes, but the `manager` should be kept as it is.
- On the `manager` scene, add an object that receives messages, and each message sets a property named `song` to a integer number. You know, if a message sensor looking for `song_1` message is activated, sets the property `song` to `1`, and so on.
- On the same object, make a logic to play each song (on loop stop mode) according to its property number. You know, if property `song` is `1`, play `song_1.ogg`, and so on.
- On each level, make an object send a message at startup to change the song. For example, `Always` > `AND` > `Message` with the subject `song_1`, and so on according to the level.

If everything went well, when a level restarts and the song is already playing, it shouldn't restart the song, and when the property `song` changes the object will stop the previous song and start the new one according to the logic.

Using this method of a `manager` scene also helps to keep everything on only one place, instead of looking for each scene to change the song or whatever.

Comment: Sorry I'm a Blender beginner.. how would I make a manager scene?

Comment: It's a regular scene, but only named `manager`, just a convention.